# Method of lines: explanation for high precision low resolution flux and vice versa

Tags: method-of-lines

Could someone please explain what is meant with e.g [high precision low resolution flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flux_limiter). Does it mean, that I use some higher order method (still first order) but with a more complex stencil and consequently lower resolution ? While low precision and high resolution means essentially a forward or backward difference formula ? As a consequence, it is on me to choose the appropriate combinations of difference methods and flux limiter (e.g by solving an analytical form of my PDE prior to the more complex one ?)